TikTok query videos research API - getting search ID is invalid or expired
I have a research account with TikTok and am using their query videos API. Documentation here.
I am trying to retrieve all videos from a single day with a search and that takes multiple calls, so after my first API call I use the cursor and search_id parameters in the next call as instructed in the API docs. However I always get an error that Search Id 7414696757969294378 is invalid or expired (with the relevant search ID).
Looks like other folks have run into this issue here. Unfortunately the TikTok support team has not gotten back to me after reaching out, so any assistance would be appreciated!
First query videos call
Request body: {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/research/video/query/?fields=id%2Cvideo_description%2Ccreate_time%2Cregion_code%2Cshare_count%2Cview_count%2Clike_count%2Ccomment_count%2Cfavorites_count%2Cmusic_id%2Chashtag_names%2Cusername%2Ceffect_ids%2Cplaylist_id%2Cvoice_to_text",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.32.3",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Authorization": {omitted},
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": "206"
    },
    "body": "{\"query\": {\"and\": [{\"operation\": \"EQ\", \"field_name\": \"hashtag_name\", \"field_values\": [\"election\"]}]}, \"start_date\": \"20230101\", \"end_date\": \"20230101\", \"max_count\": 5, \"search_id\": \"\", \"cursor\": 0}"
}
INFO:tik_tok_api:Response body: {
    "data": {
        "cursor": 5,
        "has_more": true,
        "search_id": "7414696757969294378",
        "videos": [<list of video objects>]
    },
    "error": {
        "code": "ok",
        "message": "",
        "log_id": "2024091504190332DAC901505CAC3E3B2E"
    }
}

Second query videos call
INFO:tik_tok_api:Request body: {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/research/video/query/?fields=id%2Cvideo_description%2Ccreate_time%2Cregion_code%2Cshare_count%2Cview_count%2Clike_count%2Ccomment_count%2Cfavorites_count%2Cmusic_id%2Chashtag_names%2Cusername%2Ceffect_ids%2Cplaylist_id%2Cvoice_to_text",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.32.3",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Authorization": {omitted},
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": "225"
    },
    "body": "{\"query\": {\"and\": [{\"operation\": \"EQ\", \"field_name\": \"hashtag_name\", \"field_values\": [\"election\"]}]}, \"start_date\": \"20230101\", \"end_date\": \"20230101\", \"max_count\": 5, \"search_id\": \"7414696757969294378\", \"cursor\": 5}"
}
INFO:tik_tok_api:Response body: {
    "error": {
        "code": "invalid_params",
        "message": "Search Id 7414696757969294378 is invalid or expired",
        "log_id": "2024091504190471DF3E7577323038D625"
    }
}

Thank you!

This is indeed a current bug with the API which I also documented here: https://github.com/INCT-DD/tiktok-sdk/issues/27. One workaround when searching for videos posted by a specific user, for example, is to search day by day with max_count set to 100. This should give us results that will fit a single query output and avoid having to walk along the cursors (as it wouldn't work anyway).

@AlexandreTeles Thank you for your reply! Good to know it's not just me. I'm unfortunately querying videos by hashtag and some of the hashtags have more than 100 videos per day, so I need to get the cursor and search ID working to ensure I'm retrieving all videos from a single day. Have you gotten a response from TikTok? They haven't been responsive to my support tickets or emails.

Still no response from their support team. One of our senior researchers has a direct contact with them, so feel free to leave a comment on the github issue above as they are going to see it (now, if they are going to solve it, different issue).

@AlexandreTeles Have you heard anything? We haven't gotten a response yet.

I also ran into this problem.
Until it gets fixed by tiktok you can try to repeat the request several times until it gets handled. For me it takes 2-5 retries per request until it gets handled.
